# In quantum mechanics, is there an actual difference between 'observation' and interaction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, observers, quantum-measurements

I apologize if this is just me misreading into things.

So in some cases I've read that observation is simply interaction, only given a name that's somewhat misleading to the laymen.

With the observer effect being misinterpreted as a phenomena where retaining information about a system changes that system in itself.

However what really derails this idea for me is the idea of interaction free observations such as with the [Elitzur–Vaidman bomb tester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elitzur%E2%80%93Vaidman_bomb_tester) thought experiment.

As well as this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5754) which apparently is a demonstration of quantum counterfactual communication. That implies an exchange of information mediated without any input of matter or energy.

Answer (score 1):

There are way too many terms like "observation" and "interaction" floating around. There is, however, an easy way to look at all of this:

There are two different kinds or processes in quantum mechanics: reversible and irreversible.

In a reversible process the quantum system remains undisturbed and the energy in the system stays the same. This is being described by the evolution of the wave function.

In an irreversible process an external system has to interact with the quantum system to either add energy to or to remove energy from the quantum system. The amount of this energy transfer is called "a quantum". We call this "preparation" or "emission" for the process that fixes the initial amount of energy in the system and "absorption" or "measurement" for the process that determines the final amount. This is usually described by the Born rule in standard non-relativistic QM. Once the energy of the system has changed it is not the same system as before.

The difference between a measurement and a simple absorption process is that in a measurement we retain the value of the quantum of energy (together with its momentum and angular momentum) that we are removing from the system. In a simple absorption process we don't care to know. To the quantum system it's all the same. It has lost the exact same amount of energy, whether the "observer" knows that number or doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer to the question is no: observations and interactions are one and the same thing. Mathematically they are represented by operators that act on the density matrix of whatever state is observed/interacted with.

As to the Elitzur-Vaidman (EV) thought experiment, you still have a measurement, albeit not in the basis you'd typically think of, namely the energy eigenbasis. Rather you have a measurement in the phase basis. That's why the EV setup requires a Mach-Zehnder interferometer.

To be more exact, the EV experiment is an *energy*-interaction-free measurement in the sense that there is no information retrieval in the Fock basis. It is however a *phase*-interaction-*full* measurement.

PS: To add some subtlety to the semantics, one would typically think of an observation as an operation that extracts information into a classical "format", i.e., the type of information that you and I can read with our macroscopic probes. On the other hand, an interaction is more general and doesn't necessarily require information extraction into the classical realm.

Answer (score 1):

There are differences depending upon the interpretation of QM. The main difference being whether consciousness plays a role.

However,in relational QM pioneered Rovelli in the mid 90s, there is no distinction between observer and interaction. It is essentially a refinement of the Copenhagen interpretation where the observer need not be a classical system but any system includimg a quantum one.

Answer (score 1):

A measurement is an interaction that records some information about the system being measured. The Elitzur Vaidman bomb tester (EVBT) fits into this way of thinking about measurement.

In quantum theory, and in reality, the result of a single photon going through an interferometer is affected by what happens in both arms of the interferometer. In any explanation of that experiment, any account of what is happening in reality to bring about the result, there is something going down both arms of the interferometer. The thing on each arm picks up a phase and the relative phases determine the probability at the end of the interferometer. The thing on each arm is deflected by lenses and mirrors just as light would be, so there is light in each arm.

If you put a detector in both arms only one detector will go off at a time. So you only detect light in one arm at any given time. So there is a photon you don't detect. Now suppose you tune the interferometer so that without detectors light only comes out of one port: port 1 and not the other port 2. This is explained by the existence of light in both arms carrying phase information. If you put a detector in just one arm, then the probability of a photon coming out in a single port will change to 50%. In the case where we detect a photon coming out of port 2 we will find that the detector didn't go off. However, we know it interacted with and blocked light in its arm because if it didn't the photon wouldn't have come out of port 2.

If you substitute a bomb for the detector you have the EVBT. So the EVBT is an interaction that gives you information about the bomb: it is a measurement.